# Exclude results between quotes from search

Tags: regex

I have a regex that picks up everything between curly brackets (inclusive)

Regex101 example here: https://regex101.com/r/isEbes/1

```
(?={{)(.*?)}}

Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia {{ voluptas }}  labore et {{ dolore }} eum 
<a href="{{iure}}">reprehenderit</a> qui <a href="{{ news }}">{{smart}}</a> ea."
```

This returns `{{voluptas}}` `{{dolore}}` `{{iure}}` `{{news}}` and `{{smart}}`

However, I want to exclude everything in `href=""`, so in this case `{{iure}}` and `{{news}}` should not be included.

How can I do this? E.g. I've tried `[^"](?={{)(.*?)}}[^"]` but this still captures `href="{{ item }} something elese"` https://regex101.com/r/xVDesH/1

Comment: What have you tried to meet this new requirement? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Yes, for example: `((?!.*href="{{.*).)(?!href)(?={{)(.*?)}}` but this only excludes the first result

Comment: I have tried `[^"](?={{)(.*?)}}[^"]` an it seems to match, does it ? Or something is missing in your question :)

Comment: @Philippe that matches the character after too: https://regex101.com/r/Zryy9l/1

Comment: Also [^"](?={{)(.*?)}}[^"] doesn't exclude results if not immediately bound by quotes https://regex101.com/r/9n25yf/1

Comment: Oops, sorry for that :D

Comment: The next step is you'll want to handle nested quotes or escaped quotes or nested brackets or ... Use a parser instead, regex is painful and ultimately unable to handle complex variations which are natural and obvious with a different frame of mind.

Comment: @tripleee, thanks, there are no nested quotes. It's just excluding anything in an `href=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could use a negative lookbehind, for example

```js
const text = `
Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia {{ voluptas }}  labore et {{ dolore }} eum 
<a href="{{iure}}">reprehenderit</a> qui <a href="{{ news }}">{{smart}}</a> ea."
`;

console.log( text.match(/(?<!href="[^"]*){{.*?}}/g) );
```

If the language you are using does not support variable-width lookbehind then just `(?<!href=")` would work for your example.

Using regex for this kind of thing is not fool-proof, but it may be good enough.

Comment: Regarding your penultimate paragraph, `"smart"` would be matched, no?